# How to get the history of a file using python-gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to get the history of a file using python-gitlab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may want try this:

`getrepositorytree` here path should be file path for which you want to get the history.
http://pyapi-gitlab.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=commits#gitlab.Gitlab.getrepositorytree

And also:

`getrepositorycommits`
http://pyapi-gitlab.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?highlight=commits#gitlab.Gitlab.getrepositorycommits